# expected unqualified-id before '{' token

Tags: c++, c, qt, qtcreator

```
    float f1(float d,float z, float c);
{
   return (log(d * z) - (d * z) + ((log * c - z) /c);
}

'void f2(float d,float z, float c,float &O);
{
    O = (log(d * z) - (d * z) + ((log * c - z) / c);
}

void f3(float d,float z, float c,float &O);
{
    float deystvie1,deystvie2;

    deystvie1 = (log(d * z) - (d * z);
    cout << "action1 = "<< deystvie1 << endl;

    deystvie2 = ((log * c - z) /c);
    cout << "action2 = "<< deystvie2 << endl;

    O = deystvie1 + deystvie2;
}
```

Comment: в отношении: `'void f2(float d,float z, float c,float &O);` подпись функции не должна заканчиваться точкой с запятой `;`. Удалите конечную точку с запятой

Comment: Вы имеете хотя бы отдалённое представление о правилах синтаксиса в С++?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

У вас из-за точки с запятой вот это:

```
float f1(float d,float z, float c);
```

оказывается совершенно не связано с этим:

```
{
   return (log(d * z) - (d * z) + ((log * c - z) /c);
}
```

И так во всех случаях. О чем компилятор и пытается сказать - что просто так, ни к чему не относящийся код быть не должен.

Кроме того, когда берете логарифм, надо писать log(x), а не log*x как в каждой вашей функции.

Открывающиеся скобки должны соответствовать закрывающим, понять x = (((((a; компитлятор не смолжет - как в **КАЖДОЙ** вашей функции! Вы вообще в учебник заглядывали??!?!

у и надеюсь

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cmath>
using namespace std;
```

вы в начале программы ставили?